# Image mean threshold in java

Tags: java, image

I would like to find the each pixel of image, and then I will get the total of pixel value, then I will find the mean value. I compare the each pixel value with the mean I get, if it is >255, pixel value will become 1 (represent black colour), if <255 then will become 0 (represent white colour). After that I set the new RGB colour, and draw the output image. [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RY9j.jpg)

Based on my concept, I thought the output image will be black and white image, but it just show black in colour. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8KQ8.png)

```
public class Imej {
    public void mapping(BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage binary = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        int i, j;
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        image.setRGB(i, j, new Color(pixel[i][j]).getRGB());
        ImageIO.write(binary,"png",output);
    }
}
```

This is `readimage`.

```
public void readimage() {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    File f = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(/** path **/));
        //System.out.println(image);
        mapping(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Imej a = new Imej();
    a.readimage();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `225`, or do you mean `255`? Or, do you mean `w` or `h` depending upon context?

Comment: Your *current* input image is 300x300, though.

Comment: oops...i edited jz nw..change to 255x255...but im getting same result...im getting crazy >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a mean function, that returns the mean of the pixel. Something like `int mean(int[][] pixels, int i, int j)`. Then you should change the first line in your if statement to be `if (mean(pixel, i, j) > mean) { //...`

```
        if (pixel[i][j] > mean)
                pixel[i][j]=1;
```

Should be

```
        if (mean(pixel, i, j) > mean)
                pixel[i][j]=0xFFFFFF;
```

Comment: i tried to change, but the result still same..or maybe still have another error..

Comment: thanks dude.i can create the black & white image..without creating the function..